# Further Functions JS Ninja 2 book can't get to work properly on console

Tags: javascript

I copied the book's example to see it working but it won't display what the book says it should. Here's the code part:

```
        const clark = { name: 'Clark' };
        const bruce = { name: 'Bruce' };

        function sayHello(greeting='Hello')
        {
            return '${ greeting }, my name is ${ this.name }';
        }
```

When I try it on the console, this is what I get:

```
sayHello.call(clark);
"${ greeting }, my name is ${ this.name }"
```

Could anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Template literals use backticks \` and not regular quotes like ' or ".

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the backticks (``)

```
 return `${ greeting }, my name is ${ this.name }`;
```

also as you know, you can do this

```
 return greeting + ', my name is ' + this.name;
```